# How to get custom user status on Discord.NET library

Tags: c#, discord, discord.net

I am working on a discord bot on a library like discord.net, and I don’t understand how to get a custom discord user status. Please tell me how I can implement this!

Answer (score 2):

Implemented in this pull-request: https://github.com/discord-net/Discord.Net/pull/1520

To be specific in the `Activities`property.